# Библиотека питона дискорд выдаёт ошибку в client.loop.create_task

Tags: python

Вот вся строка
`client.loop.create_task(send_random_message())`
Вот сама ошибка
`loop attribut cannot be accessed in non-async context`
Вот весь код

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

messages = [
    "Привет, как дела?",
    "Какой сегодня красивый день!",
    "Я люблю программировать.",
    "Сколько времени до обеда?",
    "Какой твой любимый фильм?"
]

async def send_random_message():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        channel = client.get_channel(1091030005292740708) 
        message = random.choice(messages)
        await channel.send(message)
        await asyncio.sleep("10") 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.loop.create_task(send_random_message())
client.run("тут токен ")
```

Comment: Дубликат: [Почему питон не хочет создавать цикл в client.loop.crate\_task](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1512697/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2-client-loop-crate-task)